# Passing struct members to function in c

Tags: c

I have a `struct` defined below for the contents of a frame to be sent over uart.

The last member of the struct is a frame check sequence (fsc) that is computed as an XOR of all the bytes in the struct members(len, cmd0, cmd1 and data). I have a function to calculate the fsc below.

My question is, how would I go about passing the struct members to `calcFCS()` which is called in `build_uart_frame()`?

Many thanks

```
typedef struct uart_frame {
  uint8_t sof;                    /* 1 byte  */
  uint8_t len;                    /* 1 bytes */
  uint8_t cmd0;                   /* 1 byte  */
  uint8_t cmd1;
  char data[11];         /* 0 -250 byte  */
  unsigned char fcs;              /* 1 byte  */                      
} uart_frame_t;

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Global uart frame
   uart_frame_t rdata;

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------
  unsigned char calcFCS(unsigned char *pMsg, unsigned char len) {

  unsigned char result = 0;
  while(len--) { 
    result ^= *pMsg++;
  }

  return(result);
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Worker code to populate the frame

int build_uart_frame() {

uart_frame_t *rd = &rdata; //pointer variable 'rd' of type uart_frame    

// common header codes
rd->sof = 0xFE;
rd->len = 11;
rd->cmd0 = 0x22;
rd->cmd0 = 0x05;
snprintf(rd->data, sizeof(rd->data), "%s", "Hello World");
rd->fcs = calcFCS(?)
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char data[11]` is exactly 11 `chars`, not 0 - 250. If you want a dynamically sized struct, the variable-sized member must be the last one.

Comment: `calcFCS((unsigned char *)rd, sizeof(uart_frame_t;) - 1)`. But this works only if `struct uart_frame` is not padded (which is unlikely here because all members are chars).

Comment: Weither use `rd` + `offsetof` to move the pointer to the corresponding member and pass that, or simply pass `rd->member` for value, or `&rd->member` for a pointer to the member... or simply pass the struct pointer in full

Comment: Standard warning: You should avoid (ab)using structs for serialization. They are inflexible, and prone to padding and endianness issues. Consider using dedicated serialization functions which convert native types to bytes in well defined manner.

Comment: @MichaelWalz thanks, struct uart_frame is not padded, I don't want to include the struct member `sof` in the fcs calculation. Does the `-1` in your reply refer to this?

Comment: @logitechmouse no, the -1 on is there, because we don't want to include the `fcs` itself into the calculation. If you dont want to include the `sof`member then you probbaly know what to do now.

Comment: @MichaelWalz, I said yesterday that the struct is not padded but in fact it is after I read up what what struct padding is. How can I prevent padding so that I can use `calcFCS((unsigned char *)rd, sizeof(uart_frame_t) - 1)`? Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you says

> a frame check sequence (fsc) that is computed as an XOR of all the bytes in the struct members(len, cmd0, cmd1 and data)

Instead of passing all member separately,better you pass pointer to `struct uart_frame`

So signature of your function should be

> unsigned char calcFCS(uart_frame* frame)

Comment: If you're passing a pointer to the struct, the `calcFCS` might as well _set_ the `fcs` member though

Comment: That's possible, too. But depends on programmer and person reviewing code, where to do assignment inside function itself OR return value from function.